# Can I get Gradle to start up faster without using the daemon?

Tags: docker, gradle, jvm

I'm running a Docker build with multiple invocations of `gradlew`, because I want to cache the results of each invocation as a build layer. In this build, the cold startup time of Gradle takes a lot of time, comparatively.

Processes don't survive between building layers, only files do, so the usual advise of "use the Gradle daemon" doesn't apply, since it'll get killed anyway.

Are there other ways to improve the Gradle startup time?

Comment: Is this some kind of CI? Try to cache the downloaded wrapper scripts ([`~/.gradle/caches`](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/caching-dependencies-895552876.html)).

Comment: @madhead It's a Dockerfile, which can be, and is, used in CI or for local development. Caching is not the issue, since files, thus cache, are persisted between the different steps. The first step is already downloading and saving gradle using the wrapper.

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom I'm also trying to set-up a multi-stage Gradle build. Would you mind sharing your Dockerfile?